# How to create a pie chart using data from Firestore in Java

Tags: java, android

Right now my code is looking like this

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

Spinner spinner;
TextView textView;
String item;
private EditText amount;
private Button save;
private Button report;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    amount = findViewById(R.id.Amount);
    save = findViewById(R.id.Save);
    String [] category = {"Food", "Gift", "Education", "Health", "Car"};
    save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v){
            int txt_amount = Integer.parseInt(amount.getText().toString());
            item = spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();


            if (txt_amount == 0){
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Empty credentials!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            else{
                FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
                Map<String, Object> users = new HashMap<>();
                users.put("Category", item);
                users.put("Amount", txt_amount);

                db.collection("Expenses").add(users).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentReference>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentReference> task) {
                        if(task.isSuccessful()){
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Values added", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                });


            }
        }
    });

    //SPINNER CODE
    spinner = findViewById(R.id.spinnerCategory);
    ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, category);
    arrayAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);


    report = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Report);
    report.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            openActivityReport();
        }
    });
    FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection("Expenses").whereEqualTo("Category", "Expense");
}

public void openActivityReport(){
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, ReportActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

public class ReportActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
private PieChart pieChart;
FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_report);


    pieChart = findViewById(R.id.activity_report_piechart);

    loadPieChartData();
    setupPieChart();
}

public void setupPieChart(){
    pieChart.setDrawHoleEnabled(true);
    pieChart.setUsePercentValues(true); // to use the percentage values on the chart
    pieChart.setEntryLabelColor(Color.BLACK);
    pieChart.setEntryLabelTextSize(12);
    pieChart.setCenterText("Spending by Category");
    pieChart.setCenterTextSize(24);
    pieChart.getDescription().setEnabled(false);
}

private void loadPieChartData(){

    db.collection("Expenses").get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
            if(task.isSuccessful()){
                for(QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()){
                    Log.d("", document.getLong("Amount") + document.getString("Category"));
                    ArrayList<PieEntry> entries = new ArrayList<PieEntry>();
                    entries.add(new PieEntry(Float.valueOf(document.getLong("Amount")),document.getString("Category")));
                    entries.add(new PieEntry(Float.valueOf(document.getLong("Amount")),document.getString("Category")));
                    entries.add(new PieEntry(Float.valueOf(document.getLong("Amount")),document.getString("Category")));
                    entries.add(new PieEntry(Float.valueOf(document.getLong("Amount")),document.getString("Category")));

                    ArrayList<Integer> colors = new ArrayList<>();
                    for(int color: ColorTemplate.MATERIAL_COLORS){
                        colors.add(color);
                    }
                    for(int color: ColorTemplate.VORDIPLOM_COLORS){
                        colors.add(color);
                    }

                    PieDataSet dataSet = new PieDataSet(entries, "Expense Category");
                    dataSet.setColors(colors);
                    PieData data = new PieData(dataSet);
                    data.setDrawValues(true); //draws the values of the different percentages
                    data.setValueFormatter(new PercentFormatter(pieChart)); //Presents the percentage
                    data.setValueTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                    data.setValueTextSize(16f);

                    pieChart.setData(data);
                    pieChart.invalidate();
                }
            }
            else{
                Log.d("", "Error getting documents ", task.getException());
            }
        }
    });
```

And my firestore database is looking like this

https://i.stack.imgur.com/vijfb.png

Is there anyway to arrange my code and to be able to create a pie chart from the data that is being stored in the firestore database. Hopefully this is enough code and the image is enough to be able to get some help

Comment: its the opposite, too match code

Comment: I mean basically the main problem I'm having is that PieEntry takes float as its value, but firestore stores its values as long and whenever I try and convert it to a float it doesn't work

Comment: Please see [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).